# Uncaught ReferenceError: test (function) is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am sorry in case my formatting of the query is incorrect... Although there are a number of threads on this topic but the suggestions can't seem to solve my issue.

I am getting the Uncaught ReferenceError: test (function) is not defined error in Google Chrome.

Following is the simplest of functions that I could create in order to isolate the issue

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function test(form){
        alert("test");
    }

</script>
```

Equally simple is the HTML here:-

```
<form id="cpmcalcform">
    <input type="button" value="Alert" onClick="test(this.form);">
</form>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ua4ja2z6/

Comment: what you have there is just Javascript, no jquery. It seems to be working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<script language="text/javascript">` is deprecated.

Use `<script type="text/javascript">`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(form){
        alert("test");
    }

</script>
<form id="cpmcalcform">
    <input type="button" value="Alert" onClick="test(this.form);">
</form>
```

Comment: With HTML5 both type and language are unneeded if the script is javascript as the default type is text/javascript http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element

Comment: `language="text/javascript"` (a) is not only deprecated. It is incorrect. The usage of language attribute was `language="javascript"` (b).  
(b) works, (a) doesn't.